# What command from python clears text from a text file?

Tags: python

I want to know how to write a command that clears a text file of all of its text? So I already have a .txt file with some text in it and everytime i execute the script it automaticly clears the .txt file  of all its text. I am new to coding and do not know much.

Comment: Oh ok, that was a quick reply let me try that!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], and read [ask] and [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic). Please note that 
[asking on Stack Overflow is not a substitute for doing your own research.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)
You can find a ton of good resources on the internet, and possibly many questions on SO that deal with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

When you open a file in write mode, it will overwrite its contents. There is no specific command that accomplishes what you're after, but this is a nifty hack:

Assuming you have this text file:

```
# foo.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

Opening it in `w` mode:

```py
with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    pass
```

Clears it:

```sh
$ cat foo.txt
$
```